# When did you last ...?

Tags: questions, time

How do I answer this type of question?

> "When did you last have your hair cut?"

Comment: Can you clarify what aspect of that is causing confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Either with a relative general time reference:

> Last week

a relative precise time reference:

> Last Monday

or an absolute time reference:

> March 3rd

or a military style reference:

> March 3rd, thirteen hundred hours

Comment: Or a different relative reference like "Two hours **ago**"

Comment: i was thinking that would be obvious, so no need to have asked the question

Comment: Unless I was in the services I think I would say "mind your own business".